# Find and replace functions in expression tree

Tags: python, sympy

I need to find all the user made functions (and things like derivatives on the user function) in a SymPy expression tree with the location to then replace with just standard user-defined symbols

```
from sympy import *
t=symbols('t')
```

Now create the user made SymPy function:

```
theta_t = Function(r'\theta')(t)
```

Also, I create the symbol that I want to replace `theta_t` with:

```
theta = Symbol(r'\theta')
```

The expression that I want to work with is:

```
y = sin(theta_t)
```

And this is its derivative with respect to `t`:

```
dydt = y.diff(t)
```

I want to find and replace `d/dt(theta(t))` and `theta_t` with symbols `omega`, `theta`. For example after substituting I want `dydt` to be:

```
dydt_new = cos(theta)*omega
```

So now I can work with this last expression numerically, e.g., with `lambdify`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just substitute derivatives like anything else. You only have to be careful about substituting the derivative before the actual function. The following works for me:

```
from sympy import *

t = symbols('t')
theta_t = Function('theta')(t)
theta = Symbol('theta')
omega = Symbol('omega')
y = sin(theta_t)
dydt = y.diff(t)

dydt_new = dydt.subs([
    ( diff(theta_t,t), omega ),
    ( theta_t, theta ),
    ])

assert dydt_new==cos(theta)*omega
```

Note how this fails if you swap the order of substitutions.